# Redirecting dynamic url to simple URL

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I'm using CodeIgniter and trying to redirect this URL

`SERVERNAME/index.php/category/category?ss=ABC` to `SERVERNAME/ABC`

What I am doing

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php/category/category?ss=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Perhaps you need `^(.*)/?$` make the trailing slash optional. Are you sure you are using the correct word _redirect_? How you are entering URL into your address bar to achieve the above format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a couple of conditions so that you don't blindly rewrite everything, then you need to make the slash optional and the `.*` non-greedy:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /index.php/category/category?ss=$1 [L]
```

Comment: i m trying to do 

SERVER/index.php/category/category?ss=abc
SERVER/abc
i put ur code i think it has to do something with codeigniter which blocking this request..